# Local rings k[[T]] and k{{T}}

Tags: algebraic-geometry, local-rings

I have a question of algebraic geometry:
A local ring is a ring having a unique maximal. Prove that rings  k[[T]] and k{{T}} are local. What are their maximal ideals ?

I see how to manage the fact that the ring of formal series k[[T]] is local, but not the ring of the Puiseux series k{{T}}. I need help to see this last part.

Thanks

Comment: Hola paula, este es un foro en inglés, por lo que si quieres optimizar el número de posible respuestas a tu pregunta te recomiendo que traduzcas la traduzcas :)

Comment: If you meant $R=K\{\{T\}\} = \bigcup_{n\ge 1} k[[T^{1/n}]]$ then the argument is mostly the same, any ideal is one of the form $\{ a\in R, v(a) > c\}$ or $\{ a\in R, v(a) \ge c\}$. Otherwise $R$ is a valuation ring, any element with non-zero constant term is a unit, and the elements with zero constant term form (the only maximal) ideal.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the presentations I've seen, $k\{\{T\}\}= \bigcup_n k((T^{1/n}))$ is a union of fields, so is itself a field by definition, and then automatically a local ring.

If you're being asked to prove this in the same context as the fact that $k[[T]]$ is local, presumably it is not safe to take this definition as automatic (i.e., maybe you have $k\{\{T\}\}$ defined using some explicit conditions on the powers of $T$ permitted to appear). But now that you know the unique maximal ideal of $k[[T]]$ to be generated by $T$, you should think about the structure of its fraction field $k((T))$ as far as the powers of $T$ that will be appearing (and similarly for the isomorphic situation of $k[[T^{1/n}]]$ with its unique maximal ideal $(T^{1/n})$ and fraction field $k((T^{1/n}))$) and show that the union I've written above really agrees with the definition you've been given.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the definition you wrote it's the definition I have.
In order to prove that k[[T]] is local I've use this argument: we have this serie $f(T)$=$a_0 + a_1T+ a_2T^2+...$ with $a_0 \not = 0$.

We can find $g(T)$ such that $f(T)·g(T)=1$
So we have some equations, like $a_0b_0=1$, $a_0b_1+a_1b_0=0$... so I can calculate each $b_i$. So any serie with non-zero constant term is a unit, and $(T)$ is its maximal ideal.

I'm not sure if I can repeat the same argument but now with the serie
$f(T)=q(T^{1/r})= a_0+ a_1T^{1/r}+a_2T^{2/r}+...$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @paula If this was intended as a comment on my answer, it may be better to post it below there for clarity. I comment on your last point in my answer: since we are treating $T$ as a formal variable, there is an isomorphism $k[[T]]\xrightarrow{\sim} k[[T^{1/n}]]$ given by taking $T\mapsto T^{1/n}$.